# Joomla как в запросе WHERE добавить условие '=JURI'?

Tags: php, sql, joomla

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сформулировать where в SQL запросе так, чтобы из БД выбирались только те строки, у которых значение 'section' равно JURI ( в коде выделено *)?

```
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(TRUE);
        $section = JURI::base(TRUE);


        $query->select($db->quoteName(array('service', 'price', 'section')));
        $query->from($db->quoteName('#__servicelist_'));
        $query->where('state = 1');
        *$query->where($section->'section');*
        $query->order('service ASC');
        $query->setlimit($params->get('section'));


        $db->setQuery($query);
        $result = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM X3table WHERE section='JURI' вы же уже пробовали?

Comment: Да, пробовал... Пишет: не определен объект JURI

Answer (score 1):

Два примера, так:

```
$query->where($db->quoteName('section') . ' LIKE '. $db->quote('JURI'));
```

или так:

```
$query->where($db->quoteName('section') . '=' . $db->quote('JURI'));
```

Comment: Денис, спасибо!

Comment: @Anton, как-то сталкивался с подобным, не за что.

Comment: а я мучаюсь с выводом данных в модуль... если проблема знакома, можно еще вопрос?

Comment: @Anton, да, давайте, может вспомню

Comment: после того как добавил $query->where($db->quoteName('section') . '=' . $db->quote('JURI')); в helper,  у меня появилась ошибка в default.php:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() и данные не выводятся

Comment: @Anton, у Вас случайно не установлен `JoomFish`? Если да, то попробуйте снести. Но для начала загляните сюда: https://github.com/GavickPro/Music-Free-Responsive-Joomla-Template/issues/103

Comment: Нет, не установлен

Comment: @Anton, вам там по идее нужно добавить условие на проверку `!=null` внутри `foreach`  и должно будет заработать

Answer (score 0):

```
$query->where($db->quoteName('section') . '=' . $db->quote('JURI'));
```